# Convert MySQL search for a pair of values in a table to Eloquent query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, where-in

I am having trouble reproducing this kind of a MySQL query using Eloquent

```
SELECT  *
    FROM    foo
    WHERE   (column1, column2) IN (('foo', 1), ('bar', 2))
```

There is a method in Eloquent query builder called `whereIn()`, but it can receive just one column as a parameter:

```
/**
 * Add a "where in" clause to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  mixed   $values
 * @param  string  $boolean
 * @param  bool    $not
 * @return $this
 */
public function whereIn($column, $values, $boolean = 'and', $not = false)
{ 
   ...
}
```

So, you can't do something like this

```
$qb = $this->model->whereIn(['column1', 'column2'], array([1, 2], [1,3], [3, 32]));
```

I am currently working very hard trying to find solution, but if anyone can help, I would be very grateful :)

EDIT:
I managed to do it this way:

```
/**
 * ...
 */
public function findConnectionsByUser(User $user, array $userConnectionIds)
{
    $qb = $this->model->query();

    ...

    return $this->createQueryBuilderForUserConnectionsWithUserIds($qb, $user, $userConnectionIds)->get();
}

/**
 * @param Builder $qb
 * @param User    $user
 * @param array   $userConnectionIds
 *
 * @return Builder
 */
private function createQueryBuilderForUserConnectionsWithUserIds(Builder $qb, User $user, array $userConnectionIds)
{
    foreach ($userConnectionIds as $userConnectionId) {
        $qb->orWhere(array(
            array('receiver_id', $user->id),
            array('initiator_id', $userConnectionId)
        ))
            ->orWhere([
                ['receiver_id', $userConnectionId],
                ['initiator_id', $user->id]
            ]);
    }

    return $qb;
}
```

EDIT 2 (more scalable solution):

```
$qb = $this->model->query();
$oneSide = $this->model->newQuery()->where('receiver_id', '=', $user->id)
            ->whereIn('initiator_id', $userConnectionsIds);

return $qb->where('initiator_id', '=', $user->id)
            ->whereIn('receiver_id', $userConnectionsIds)
        ->union($oneSide)->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to nest them like

```
$qb = $this->model->whereIn('column1', [1, 2, 3])
->orWhere(function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('column2', [2, 3, 32]);
});
```

Also not sure if you could simply use to whereIn like this. Just try first

```
$qb = $this->model->whereIn('column1', [1, 2, 3])
->whereIn('column2', [2, 3, 32]);
```

The first query reads more like `OR` and the second more like an `AND` query.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem before I saw your answer.
But, for small test, I adapted your code for my purposes, and it seems to be working,
Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit crude, but you could concatenate the columns to one, separating the two with some otherwise unused character like '|'.

Comment: Hmm..
I don't think this could help.